# Why do I not have a /boot/config.txt fle?

Tags: raspbian, screen, config.txt

I have a Raspberry pi B, and downloaded and installed "2012-10-28-wheezy-raspbian.img." I am using a 3.5 inch VGA TFT-LCD monitor, where the tiny font was hard to read, but I have managed to increase it (thanks to recantha, who answered my question "how") using "setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat15-TerminusBold20x10.psf.gz". But now there is a letter missing on any line that reaches the right hand edge of the screen. I believe I should amend "/boot/config.txt" to correct this but I do not have that file, although all references suggest it should be there already.

At first I could not find out how to turn the thing off, and I thought that unplugging it may have corrupted things, so I have just downloaded the .img and flashed the SD card again. Two things puzzle me: I still do not have a "/boot/config.txt" file; and the font came up big and bold, whereas I would have expected it to go back to the original size, so where was that information carried over the re-installation?

I'm still floundering, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you run the setup properly at the first boot?Also you can run it again using the command

```
$sudo raspi-config
```

To manually add the file, just add a new file config.txt to the /boot folder.You can find the options from the [elinux](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig) website.

I think changes are made to the firmware so it was still there after reflashing the sd card.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Stevelrwin for your reply. I boot up by switching on, nothing else. I tried    $sudo raspi-config and got: sudo: raspi-config: command not found. Is it possible that I have not done the flash of the SD card correctly -- I followed the instructions in "http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup" carefully

Comment: Sorry could not get formatting sorted in time on that last comment

Comment: did you try installing it using sudo apt-get install raspi-config.Might work after that!

Comment: Thanks again SteveIrwin, I flashed the SD card again, and have now got raspi-config going. So it looks solved.....

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "rpi-update". Last time I ran it, I remember it spoke about the config.txt file. Maybe it will generate a new one ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that tib20. As I said in a previous comment, it is all ok now after flashing the SD card again, and I have successfully edited config.txt and used raspi-config.