# How to find the config.txt on noobs

Tags: sd-card, hdmi, config.txt

I am trying to use an hdmi screen with my pi but in order to do that I need to go into the config.txt... I cannot find the config.txt in my NOOBS sd card. Is there a way to find that or make one?

Comment: What have you tried (cannot find doesn't help)? What computer are you using? Can you list the partitions on the SD card?

Comment: @Milliways I've tried to add a boot folder and add my config.txt everywhere but it doesn't take... I'm just using Windows to open my ad card which only has one partition

Comment: Trying to create directories is a mistake. I have not used NOOBS for years but it creates additional `FAT32` partitions which Windows can't (or refuses) to mount. Frankly I think NOOBS is overly complex. It is OK when it works, but it is far easier to just install a Raspbian image on the card.

Answer (score 1):

I would start over. If you have started making or building files and directories and moving things or deleting things you are going to spend a lot of time trying to fix things that never should have been messed with. Burn Raspbian or NOOBS from Raspberrypi.org according to the instructions given on the downloads page.

After you reinstall do not make,remove, or delete files and folders before you check simple things like spelling, punctuation and spacing as you type them in the terminal. Make sure you use sudo or have permission to do what are trying to do.

You stated you did not think you had a boot folder, and also you made a boot folder to create a config.txt file. I will tell you this..you may have deleted, moved or renamed it but at one time you did. I personally do NOT mess around with folders like boot without caution and backing up my system. I would suggest you spend some time learning the file tree, how it works and what the files and folders are used for. Raspberry pi is very forgiving. You can mess up and just burn a new image to reinstall and keep going a million times. By taking time to learn about your system and how it works you wont need to reinstall a million times.

This is not the answer you are looking for, but they way you asked the question and what you are asking for I believe this is the answer you need. There may be a series of commands that could potentially save the day and undo what has been done, but if you are just planning on typing in commands that you never understand you will always have problems. If you always have problems you are not having fun, and if you are not having fun what is the point. Trust me I was given the advice I am giving you. I was offended at first but I gave it a try and it is fun it takes effort but it is worth it.

Comment: Hi I'm here from the future to state that I started from NOOBS and definitely have no boot folder. I'm having the same problem as OP (need to edit a config file to get HDMI to work). Installing Raspbian now to see if that has the `/boot/config.txt` I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have video output on a TV, you can access and modify the config.txt file by entering the recovery mode. Press SHIFT at boot, and then you will have a window with a "Edit Config" label.
From there you will be able to edit and save the relevant config.txt.

[Here](http://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/force-raspberry-pi-output-to-composite-video-instead-of-hdmi/03/03/2014/) 
you will find screenshots of said screens.

Also, if you do not have a config.txt file, you might be interested in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/why-do-i-not-have-a-boot-config-txt-fle) and in [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=85192&p=601910).

Comment: I done have the config file though... It doesn't exist. Any tips on how to build one?

Comment: See my edit, hope it helps.

Comment: that is a good link thank you... I don't even have a boot folder though :(

Comment: that's what you think. Open a terminal and type "nano /boot/config.txt" or "cd /boot"...

Comment: it just tells me no such file or directory